# ubuntu postgresql 12 : Out of memory: Killed process (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, out-of-memory

I am using unbuntu 20.04 and postgresql 12 .
My memory is 128 GB , SDD is 1TB. Cpu is i7 (16 core 20 threads)

I made simple c++ program which connect postgresql and generting tile map (just map image).
It's similar with [osmtilemaker](https://github.com/Magellium/osmtilemaker).
Once program starts, it takes serveral hours to servral months to finish job.

For first 4~5 hours, it runs well.
I monitored memory usage, and It doesnot occupy more than 10% of whole Memory at most.

Here is the screenshot of top command

```
Tasks: 395 total,  16 running, 379 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 70.3 us,  2.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 26.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 128565.5 total, 111124.7 free,  11335.7 used,   6105.1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2003.6 free,     44.4 used. 115108.6 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2217811 postgres  20   0 2369540   1.7g 678700 R  99.7   1.3  25:27.36 postgres
2217407 postgres  20   0 2393448   1.7g 678540 R  99.0   1.4  25:32.04 postgres
2217836 postgres  20   0 2352936   1.7g 679348 R  98.0   1.3  25:26.22 postgres
2217715 postgres  20   0 2368268   1.7g 680144 R  97.7   1.3  25:29.78 postgres
2217684 postgres  20   0 2384308   1.7g 679248 R  97.3   1.4  25:29.49 postgres
2217539 postgres  20   0 2386156   1.7g 680124 R  97.0   1.4  25:30.46 postgres
2216651 postgres  20   0 2429348   1.8g 678128 R  95.7   1.4  26:05.99 postgres
2217025 postgres  20   0 2396408   1.7g 679292 R  94.4   1.4  25:51.85 postgres
2238487 postgres  20   0 1294752  83724  54024 R  14.3   0.1   0:00.43 postgres
2238488 postgres  20   0 1294968 219304 189116 R  14.0   0.2   0:00.42 postgres
2238489 postgres  20   0 1294552  85624  56068 R  12.6   0.1   0:00.38 postgres
2062928 j         20   0  861492 536088  47396 S   6.6   0.4  19:18.64 mapTiler
2238490 postgres  20   0 1290132  73244  48084 R   6.3   0.1   0:00.19 postgres
2238491 postgres  20   0 1289876  73064  48160 R   6.3   0.1   0:00.19 postgres
 928763 postgres  20   0 1181720  61368  59300 S   0.7   0.0  11:59.45 postgres
1306124 j         20   0   19668   2792   2000 S   0.3   0.0   0:06.84 screen
2238492 postgres  20   0 1273864  49192  40108 R   0.3   0.0   0:00.01 postgres
2238493 postgres  20   0 1273996  50172  40852 R   0.3   0.0   0:00.01 postgres
      1 root      20   0  171468   9564   4864 S   0.0   0.0   0:09.40 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 kthreadd
```

I used 8 threads in program, so 8 process is using cpu a lot ,
but memory usage is always below 10%.

But, after 4~5 hours, oom-killer killed postgres processes and program stopped running.
Here is the result of dmesg

```
[62585.503398] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),
cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,
task_memcg=/system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@12-main.service,
task=postgres,pid=463942, uid=129

[62585.503406] Out of memory: Killed process 463942 (postgres) 
total-vm:19010060kB, anon-rss:17369476kB, file-rss:0kB, 
shmem-rss:848380kB, UID:129 pgtables:36776kB oom_score_adj:0
```

It looks like out of memory error.
But, how that can happend when I have free memory more than 100GB?

Comment: You don't have free memory, at least not when the error happens. I'd look for memory leaks in the C++ program.

Comment: So it doesn't take much memory, until suddenly it does.  Without knowing the internal workings of your code, it is hard to speculated on why it works like that.  If you follow the docs for preventing overcommit (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT) you should at least get better error messages.

Comment: I restarted program. and It is running 10 hours or so until now..  I can't predict when the out-of-memory error will happen again.   I am watching TOP command from time to time.  If something happens, I will let you know.  thanks.